# I am trying to fetch asset using local identifier in collection view using dispatch background but it takes too much time to load and cell are empty

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, grand-central-dispatch, phasset

I am trying to load asset from local identifier using fetch assets from local identifier  in cell for item 
at indexpath in background thread and displaying it in collection view cells but it takes too much time to load and cells are nil.there are hundred of images.here is the code.

does this approach is correct for fetching assets in cellfor indexpath??

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "GridCell", for: indexPath) as! GridCell

cell.representedAssetIdentifier = "localidentifier"

    DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                if let cachedImage = self.imageCache.object(forKey: localidentifier! as NSString) as? UIImage {
                    cell.image  = cachedImage

                }
            }

            //let asset = self.assetsByDate[indexPath.section].1[indexPath.row]
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                 let asset = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withLocalIdentifiers: [localidentifier!], options: .none).firstObject
                let mystring  = String(describing: asset)
                //print("the asset to string \(mystring)")
               // print ("String to asset \( mystring as! PHAsset)")


                self.imageManager.requestImage(for:  asset!, targetSize: self.thumbnailSize, contentMode: .aspectFit, options: PHImageRequestOptions(), resultHandler: { result, info in
                    if cell.representedAssetIdentifier =="localidentifier" {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async() {

                            DispatchQueue.main.async() {


                                if let image = result {
                                    self.imageCache.setObject(image, forKey:localidentifier!  as NSString)
                                    cell.image= image
                                }

                            }
                        }

                    }
                })

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if you load image in background thread (and that's a good point), the cell shouldn't be nil. So I think the probleme is not exactly there.

In your case the method should return a cell with an ImageView even if the image is still loading.
Then, when loading will be ended, it should display the image in the imageView.

The probleme may also come from the duplicate line about main thread :

```
DispatchQueue.main.async() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async() {
```

You should remove one of them.
You also have to use a weak reference to avoid nil exception or leak:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async() { [weak self] in
    if let image = result {
        self.imageCache.setObject(image, forKey:localidentifier!  as NSString)
    cell.image= image
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried but still it takes too much time to load if i scroll up images become empty for some cells

Comment: Hi maxime r u available?

Comment: does this approach is correct for fetching image from local identifier in cell for item at indexpath ??

Comment: are you sure it's just a probleme of delay. Are you sure the image is not nil when loading is over?

Comment: in prepare for reuse i am making imageview as nil  
        image.image = nil
         super.prepareForReuse() but if i wont use , cells is repeating previous images

Comment: Yes you have to do it, but are you sure this condition returns true? : if let image = result {

Comment: is the approach correct for fetching asset in cellfor indexpath??????pls answer my question?

Comment: I said YES. this is the right place to fetch data if you don't want your controller to be too large

Comment: it is taking too much time to load images. if i scroll up again some cells become empty i am using cache also

Comment: I think your cache doesn't work or doesn't work well, otherwise your image should be displayed at once on scroll up.

Comment: when i scroll fast dispath background doesnot call                  let asset = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withLocalIdentifiers: [localidentifier!], options: .none).firstObject...it skips to loop

Comment: maybe you can try to change the queue .background by .userInteractive

Comment: no its .background only.. i have checked if i fast scroll inside .background thread skips comes to end of loop